# Follow path parent not working

Tags: constraints

I have an object. Ive created a path. I select both. Right click and choose "follow path".  Nothing happens. Ive used this countless times. Before but for some reason its not working now. Ive tried with follow path curve and bezier curve. Ive adjusted on the graph the frames for the animation to take effect. Ive always ensured animation in selected in the curve menu as well as frames and evaluation time.

Even when i click on the curve - sometimes it wont show on the graph

Do not want to use follow path constraint because i can never figure out the axis

Comment: If you change the Evaluation Time in the curve  > Data > 'Path Animation' does the object move? (But not move when you scrub the timeline?)

Comment: Does not not do anything

Comment: Hmm. That's blown my possible solution away.. :(. Maybe share a representative part of your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  ?

Comment: Is the Path Animation option activated?

Comment: Yes path is animated